# Как сделать рывок в юнити?

Tags: unity3d

Как сделать рывок в юнити3д?????????

Comment: изучить юнити :)

Comment: Да никто блин не знает!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Можешь использовать метод **AddForce**
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html